# update with order sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to update a `column` in table using `sqlalchemy` with `order_by`, it works fine with `mysql` as follow :

```
UPDATE `user` SET `order` = `order`+1 ORDER BY `order` DESC;
```

But if i try it using `sqlalchemy` :

```
session.query(User).order_by(User.order).update({'order': Table.order + 1})
```

I get the `error` :

> Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when order_by() has been called

is there a way to implement it using `sqlalchmey`?

Edit:
order is needed because the column is unique

Comment: Is `ORDER BY order DESC` clause is really necessary ? I don't see the purpose of this clause here, `UPDATE user SET order = order+1`  would be enough for what you are trying to do

Comment: `ORDER BY` can usually not be used with `UPDATE`, just as it can't be used within a subquery: The statement has to specify which rows to update and there is no order within those rows.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ORDER BY order DESC is important because the filed is unique if i update without order i get unique constraint exception

Comment: Please provide database structure as I think that here is where the problem lies.

Comment: Did this get solved? I'm having the exact same problem. A table in my SQLite database has an `order` column for displaying purposes and it is `UNIQUE`. When reordering them using SQLAlchemy I want to add 1 to a portion of them, but I'm getting a Unique Constraint Failed error. I'm assuming because it is modifying their order values one by one, and starting with lower values.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting param deferrable=True when init UniqueConstraint?

```
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'   
    name = Column('name', String, unique=True),
    order = Column('order', Integer),

    UniqueConstraint(                                                                                                                                                              
        'order', name='unikey_order',                                                                                                                    
        deferrable=True                                                                                                                                                            
    ) 
# update directly
db.session.query(User).update({User.order: User.order + 1}, synchronize_session='fetch')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sqllite and you can't set `deferrable=True`, you can use this workaround that breaks the update into two updates:

```py
update_stmt_1 = (
    update(User)
    .values(order=-(User.order + 1)
)

update_stmt_2 = (
    update(User)
    .where(User.order < 0)
    .values(order=-User.order)
)

db.session.execute(update_stmt_1)
db.session.execute(update_stmt_2)
```

The first statement sets the `order` value to the negative of what it should be, avoiding constraint conflicts during row-by-row update.

The second inverts the negative values, setting everything to the properly updated value.

I tested this and ensured that both of the statements still occur within the same transaction.

Found method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758778/1124794